# Create a Blob from a returned nodeJS buffer in JSON format

Tags: node.js, json, blob, buffer, arraybuffer

In nodeJS I have a Buffer variable.

From the client I fetch to the server to get this variable. This Buffer has been converted to json format with `Buffer.toJSON()`.

How can I create a Blob in the client with this response?

In nodeJS (with Express):

```
app.route('/api').post( async (req, res) => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from('This is a test buffer')
    const jsonBuffer = Buffer.toJSON()
    res.json(response)      
})
```

In the client (with fetch):

```
const rawResponse = await fetch('/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
    body: JSON.stringify('nothing')
})
const response = await rawResponse.json()
const blob = new Blob(response.data, {type: 'text/html'})   // This doesn't work

console.log(blob)
```

Comment: May be this work: `const uint8 = new Uint8Array(response.data)` 
. And then create the blob:
`const blob = new Blob([uint8], {type: 'text/html'})`